# R CMD roxygen - exec: 65: roxygen: not found

Tags: r, roxygen

Roxygen works fine from within R, but for some reason it craps out when I try to call it from the command line. Noticed a similar complaint from someone on windows (this thread: [R CMD roxygen not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389070/r-cmd-roxygen-not-recognized))  but I'm on a nix box right now. Tried installing from source (`install.packages("roxygen", type="source")`) no dice there.

Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe you need to load the library before calling roxygen()?

Comment: My understanding was that it would show up as one of the CMD in the list `R CMD --help.`. In any case, I just wrote another little script and used `R CMD BATCH` instead.

Comment: Only works with linux source installs and even then is fragile. No longer supported in roxygen2.

Comment: @hadley I'm reporting the problem from Ubuntu 11.04. "Fragile", got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't have an answer as the package it is questioning is essentially deprecated.

Use roxygen2 instead and write a shell script to roxygenize code from within R at the time of packaging.